# How to import a C++ library into a Xcode Objective C project?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode4

I'm new to developing apps for OSX. I want to write a library that does a specific job in C++ and use it inside my XCode Objective-C/Objective-C++ project.

How should I compile and prepare the C++ library so it can be imported into XCode?

Comment: It would probably help to know how the library is currently being built. Manual makefile, autotools, Visual Studio, some other build system, as part of another, non-XCode application etc.?

Comment: @pmjordan, I'm not quite sure which is the way to go. I prefer writing the library code in Visual Studio but makefile is okay too. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Oh okay, so it's not existing code you want to import. XCode has target templates for static and dynamic libraries, I suggest you use the one that suits you better (static is probably easier).

Answer (score 1):

There are Xcode templates for C++ libraries. Just make one of those and copy the library's source into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Compile Sources As: Objective-C++ in your build settings.